# Filling canvas with fillRect() and getting color of each pixel returns array with 4 zeros

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

To be straight, I made two canvases, which are filled with part of the JSFiddle logo. The problem is that whenever I want to get color of each pixel with `getImageData().data`, it returns an empty array meaning the pixel is transparent, what is not true. The problem code:

```
for (i = 0; i < h; i+=scale)
    for (j = 0; j < w; j+=scale) {
        rgba1 = sctx.getImageData(i,j,1,1).data;
        rgba2 = sctx2.getImageData(i,j,1,1).data;
        // logging
        log('x:'+i/5+' | y:'+j/scale+' | '+rgba1);
        log('x:'+i/scale+' | y:'+j/scale+' | '+rgba2,true);
    }
```

Printed result:

[image: result]

What's the problem with the code? [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwf5xc8v/8/embedded/js,result/)

Comment: @markE edited, thanks :)

Comment: Is this your own image, on the same domain, or are you loading it from a different domain? Because CORS and the browser security model do not allow you to read pixels painted by images that are not your own.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, if there were a Cross Origin issue, as you said, the browser won't allow him to read pixels. Hence there will just be a security error and not an empty imageData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your output. 
Your canvas has a landscape orientation, your coordinates indicate portrait mode.

```
for (i = 0; i < w; i+=scale)
    for (j = 0; j < h; j+=scale) {
```

Comment: You found OP's error, but what it actually does is to always check at coordinates x:0 y:0-35